# Are there weapons specialized for fighting Divine Casters?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, weapons, divine

In D&D, Arcane Casters have to deal with weapons like Mage Bane enchantments for those who target casters.

Are there any sort of weapons that specialize in fighting divine casters, like Mage Bane weapons?

Comment: The Defiant prestige class comes to mind, though while the abilities often counter divine based stuff, it doesn't really extend to weapons, nor does it gain any bane effects. (Planar Handbook, p44) The is also an adventure which had a Black Rain, that functioned as a wide area divine cancellation effect, sort of like anti magic shell, but for divine.

Answer (score 1):

### No, there aren't in official sourcebooks content.

In official sourcebooks there are no weapons specialized in fighting divine casters. If you ask about in a third party content is almost impossible to be sure.

I had a player with a hypothesis about this. He said that different from arcane abilities, divine spellcasting are usually more tied with morality (alignments) and weapons against those specific alignments are good against a most of the divine followers of a deity in question. While following this hypothesis allow you to raise arms against the followers of a deity, a crusade against all divine spellcasters seems unlikely.